# Is there a way to relieve connect to the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asp.net-mvc, afnetworking

I am fairly new to IOS programming 
So I do not even know how to ask exactly
But I will explain the problem
I created an application that relies mainly to fetch data from the server sometimes the size of json is too large
Is there a way to save json on the device and not to bring, but recent data or only work to synchronize with the server
the program is objective c and i uses afnetworking
back end is ASP.net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way to handle this use case is, you always store the latestItemId/latestItemTimestamp in your app and every time you need to get new data, you make a call to the server with this information. In your server endpoint, you use this id/timestamp and get data after this id/timestamp.

When the app requests the api endpoint for the first time, the value of latestItemId will be 0. After getting the data every time, you keep updating it. Since you are asking the server to give data only after a specific id, you will only get the needed data (latest data)

For example your server code might look like (using EF and LINQ) *(The below code is to give you an idea. I did not check for compilation errors*)

```
public List<string> Messages(int fromId=0,int top=20)
{
   var d = yourDbContext.Messages
                        .Where(x=>x.Id>fromId)
                        .OrderBy(f=>f.InsertTime)
                        .Take(top)
                        .Select(c=>c.MessageBody)
                        .ToList();
   return d;
}
```

From the IOS client app side, You can keep the data(latestId) in the app memory and/or use `NSUserDefaults` to store it. `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` method might be helpful (In Swift)